# How to change the font in android settings using Robotium?

Tags: android, robotium

Can I change font size from medium to large or tiny in Android Settings via Robotium? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly sure that `Robotium` doesn't provide this feature. `Robotium` is an instrumentation test framework, which is close to your app's UI , so if your app doesn't provide this feature in its own interface, `Robotium` won't do it.

Although, lately I'd read about Google's UI test framework `uiautomator` and it seems to have this feature. To prove that assumption read this

[Android: Espresso test for lock screen/main screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351750/android-espresso-test-for-lock-screen-main-screen)

http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html

So please try to find out more about this `uiautomator` framework which might be great addition to your existing `Robotium` tests.